# ubuntudde-dde not found on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, ppa, deepin-desktop-environment

I want install the Deepin Desktop, and have added
the ubuntudde-dev ppa (In the Software & Updates Program 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntudde-dev/stable/ubuntu/' is checked). I ran `sudo apt update`, but I alway get the Error:

`E: Unable to locate package ubuntudde-dde`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A package named `ubuntudde-dde` does not exist in this repository, at least not for 22.04 as you can see [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntudde-dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+index?field.series_filter=jammy).

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can't find ubuntutude-dde in the UbuntuDDE repository.  UbuntuDDE is a Linux distribution which includes the Deepin Desktop Environment as its default environment.  The question is how to find ubuntutude-dde which is an addon package for other distributions in the Debian family which don't include it by default.